# How to copy a checkbox state from one to another

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Lets say I have this code here with 2 buttons copy inputa to inputb and copy inputb to inputc :

```
<input id="inputa" type="checkbox" name="input[1][]"> 


<input id="inputb" type="checkbox" name="input"> 


<input id="inputc" type="checkbox" name="input[2][]">
```

What I would like is to copy the state of haircolor0 to haircolor1 through a click of a button using JQuery. Then using the same method I would copy from haircolor 1 to 0. to simulate a copy and paste so my user can just copy and paste their choices through the form. Would not like to use a loop.

Not really great with JQuery just learning. Need help

A template what I mean, just need the functions to complete this.

http://jsfiddle.net/andrewvmail/ujhaC/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly. You should show code what you have done.

[Made jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6kfsW/1/)

jQuery :

```
$('.copy').click(function(){

    // button id
   var id = $(this).attr('id');

    //loop through checked inputs
    $('.' + id + ':checked').each(function(){
        var inputId = $(this).attr('id').split('-'),
           value = inputId[0], number = inputId[1] ;

        //check checkboxes
         $("#" + value + "-" + (parseInt(number)+1) ).attr('checked', 'checked');
    }); 

});
```

Comment: Yes that's what I want without the loop and the use of class selector. Just imagine it's always 1 select box you are copying it from.

Comment: Yes thats' exactly what I want except when you play about with it the function starts to break...